# xtensor-blas incorrect computation

Tags: c++, openblas, xtensor

I'm trying to use xtensor-blas for the first time. I've had [lots of difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874119/cannot-use-xtensor-blas-on-windows) linking to it, but finally, I've done that and tried to run the [sample programs](https://xtensor-blas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). However, as the output, I get `0` for the first and `0, -inf` for the second.

I'm using `Windows 10 x64`, `Clion 2021.1`
Installed `cmake 3.19.7`, `xtensor 0.23.4`, `xtensor-blas 0.19.0`, `openblas 0.3.13`, `lapack 3.6.1` using `anaconda`
Compiled using `Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(tstxtensor6)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(xtensor)
find_package(xtensor-blas)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} xtensor xtensor-blas)
```

```cpp
#include <xtensor-blas/xlinalg.hpp>

int main()
{
    {
        xt::xarray<double> a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        auto d = xt::linalg::det(a);
        std::cout << d << std::endl;  // 6.661338e-16
    }
    {
        xt::xarray<double> a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        auto d = xt::linalg::slogdet(a);
        std::cout << std::get<0>(d) << ", " << std::get<1>(d) << std::endl;  // 1, -34.9450...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are raising a good point. However, the question would improve by formulating what you would expect (mathematically), what you get from the program, and why you think this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the example, that uses a singular matrix. Its determinant should be 0 as your code outputs correctly.

This case was discussed in a [pull request](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-blas/pull/192/files) for xtensor-blas, and the solution was to change the example.